# MAMP PRO will not start MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

I have MAMP & MAMP PRO. MAMP is working okay, this can successfully start Apache and MySQL and performs normally. MAMP PRO will refuse to start MySQL. I have tried the following setting:

```
innodb_recovery_force = 1
```

This was not effective, even when set to level 6. I've tried deleting the two log files contained within the MySQL DB folder. This was also not successful.

I do not care about the databases, I want a fresh clean start. However MAMP PRO refuses to work.

Below is the error log out put:

```
2017-11-24 20:52:31 10804 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace macs2014_internal/btcontentlocal uses space ID: 358 at filepath: .\macs2014_internal\btcontentlocal.ibd. Cannot open tablespace tripeasi_whitelabel_mobile/authtypeconcretecookiemap which uses space ID: 358 at filepath: .\tripeasi_whitelabel_mobile\authtypeconcretecookiemap.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\tripeasi_whitelabel_mobile\authtypeconcretecookiemap.ibd
```

I have tried completely reinstalling MAMP multiple times however it still appears to be looking for these databases which no longer exist. As I said before, I do not care about saving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the folder on windows located in your public documents for MAMP PRO. This is why none of my settings were working correctly and why these phantom databases were appearing.

I went to:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\db
```

and deleted the databases from there, restarted my server and voila - it works. This is a very confusing place to put the settings for MAMP PRO and I don't really understand why they are there and not where you'd expect them to be in your program files.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other MySQL processes or Server running at the same time that you are trying to start the MySQL server on MAMP? (this can be checked using te "top" command in terminal)

When I first installed MAMP Pro, MySQL Server (MAMP) could not start, that because a MySQL server was already running. (configured to start automatically with the OS)

If so, you can kill all MySQL processes (don't forget to stop the MAMP servers before) using following command in the terminal: `sudo killall -9 mysqld`.

An other thing you can try, is:

- Quit MAMP
- In the finder go to `Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/`
- Delete the log files
- Restart MAMP

I hope that your problem is solved after trying one of those things.

Kind regards,

Dakta

Comment: Apologies I should of mentioned I'm using Windows. I've tried deleting the log files but this was not successful.